# Specifying font with enscript

Tags: printing, postscript, enscript

I've read the man page for `enscript` but cannot find the answer to this problem. I am trying to print using `enscript` with a downloaded AFM file but I can't get it to work. I keep getting the following error:

```
$ enscript foo.txt -B -f OCRA10 -p - > foo.ps;
couldn't open AFM file for font "OCRA", using default
```

I have downloaded the AFM file for OCRA and it is located at `/usr/share/fonts/ocr/OCRA.afm`. I've rebuilt the font cache with `fc-cache -fv`. I also added a local enscript config file with the path for AFM files:

```
$ cat ~/.enscriptrc 
AFMPath: /usr/share/fonts/ocr
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than scanning all AFM files looking for the name of the given font, `enscript` only scans the `font.map` text file. This file is a simple two-column ASCII file where each line has the format `FontName filename`. If you place the AFM file in `enscript`'s `afm` directory (on my system it's located at `/usr/share/enscript/afm`) and then add a line in the `font.map` file (located in the same directory), it will then be able to find and use the font.

I don't know but would guess that any path you give in the `AFMPath:` field of the config file would also need a `font.map` file. This would be necessary if you don't have root access to the system and cannot write to `enscript`'s directory.

Comment: Note that the `font.map` file can be generated by `mkafmmap` which comes with `enscript` : `cd /your/afm/dir; mkafmmap *.afm` will create the file.