# Enscript: How to use a different font?

Tags: fonts, enscript

I downloaded the font `RobotoMono-Regular.ttf` [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono?selection.family=Roboto%20Mono), converted it to `RobotoMono-Regular.afm` with [this tool](https://convertio.co/ttf-afm/) and copied this file to `/usr/local/share/enscript/afm` where other `.afm`  files reside. In there is also the file `font.map`. I added the entry `RobotoMono-Regular RobotoMono-Regular` (the first entry is the font name, the second the file base name of the `.afm`. When I use `enscript --font=RobotoMono-Regular ...`, I don't get the new font, though. Is there anything else that needs to be done? File permissions seem all fine. If I specify the font names of other fonts saved as `.afm` in this directory, `enscript` respects them.

This is under macOS. The question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169102/specifying-font-with-enscript) seems somewhat related but is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.afm` files are font metrics, that say how much space to leave for each character, so enscipt can calculate where to put line breaks and so on.  To actually draw the characters a printer also needs the PostScript code describing how to draw each character. This is in a separate `.pfa` (or `.pfb`) file that you must also provide in the `afm` directory, with the same basename as the `.afm` file.

Check if the pfa files was also generated by your web-tool. If not, you can use `ttf2pt1` which should be in some suitable package for your system.

When enscript sees the 2 files, it "downloads" the pfa file so it is included into the output and the printer then knows how to print everything.  The other fonts you see there without a pfa file are standard fonts that the printer is expected to have built-in, so no download is needed. Using `enscript -v` should show you a message like

```
downloading font "RobotoMono-Regular"
```

By printer, I include programs like GhostView (`gv`) and so on.